# android addJavascriptInterface webside

Tags: javascript, android

I'm following google developer guides for android get javascript message,android side work good as well,but webside get error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Android' of undefined
may webside code:

```
function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    Android.showToast(toast);
    $('#form_id').submit(); //can't keep going because error
}
```

how to fix this error?? thanks!!

Comment: refer this [link](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/binding-javascript-and-android-code-example/).

Comment: how do you use `addjavascriptinterface` method? How have you declared your javascript interface class?